# Bordered Silverlight table

Tags: silverlight

I've used this technique to create a bordered table in Silverlight:

[How to create a bordered table in Silverlight?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2794538/silverlight-how-to-create-a-bordered-table?answertab=active#tab-top)

Works OK except that the outer border of the grid is half the thickness of all the other inner cells' borders and that looks terrible. How do I get all the borders of my "table" the same including the outer border of the whole grid?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Border Style="{StaticResource borderStyle}" BorderThickness={Binding BorderThickness, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}>
    <!-- Cell content here -->
</Border>
```

Comment: So you copied and pasted the code from the link I supplied. Really?!

Comment: Well it doesn't work. The outer border of the grid remains thinner than that of the individual cells.